# Как легко добавить 30+ объектов в ArrayList?

Tags: java, массивы

Пишу на Java

Был массив `String[] iso_third = { "0.8", "2", ..., "33" }; //30+ значений`

Но мне нужно добавлять в него еще одно значение, либо в начале, либо в конце (в зависимости от расчетов программы).
Подскажите как правильно это сделать. Может создать динамический `ArrayList`? Как тогда по быстрому в него добавить 30+ значений? (Значения идут не по порядку).

Comment: А как тяжело, и что собственно значит тяжело? А легко - это как рукой взмахнуть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String[] iso_third = { "0.8", "2", ..., "33" };
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(iso_third)); //добавление всех предыдущих элементов в список

    list.add(0, "значение");//добавление значения по индексу в начало
    list.add("значение"); //добавление в конец
```

Если добавление в конец, то `list.add();`, если в начало - то добавление по индексу, а индекс первого элемента 0.

Answer (score 1):

С учетом статического импорта:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
```

или `List#addAll`

Comment: Нет такой конструкции, `ArrayList<>(asList`, правильно `ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList`

Comment: Это написано с учетом статического импорта вообще-то.

Comment: Надо было импорт тоже привести. А то как остальные люди поймут.